# Accessing MySQLWorkbench Queries

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

Our database only has a couple of Users.Despite warnings of not opening to many tabs on MySQL Workbench (as performance tails off) one has succeeded in creating nearly 100 query tabs with the result that Workbench is so slow as to be virtually unusable. I am tempted to a complete removal of Workbench and a reinstall. However he says there a a number of complex queries he wants to get copies of. Is it possible to access these via another route?

He is running Workbench Version 5.2.38 under Linux Mint

Comment: The issue is on his PC which connects to the server...

Comment: I can connect tot he server from another PC without problem. The issue is with Workbench on one specific user's PC. He has been told robustly to keep copies of his development work but the requirement is to access the queries he has been working on via Workbench.

Comment: OK, so you want the query history executed from that instance of Workbench? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28434342/544342) (confirmed in my experience as well) the query history for the user's install can be found at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log\`.

Comment: Pathis not totally correct as it is a Linux and not a Windows PC.The path is /home/<user>/.mysql/workbench/sql_history.There are dozens of XML documents here containing the queries run. I suspect the Workbench tabs are not built upfrom here are they seem contiguous and tabs can be deleted. The .mysql donates a hidden directory...

Comment: 100 query tabs is just crazy. Every tool will have trouble with such a huge amount. Also upgrade WB. The current version is 6.3.9.

Comment: I found the 'tab' contents in /home/<user>/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/<host>-1.autosave. Using the Linux shell I found and copied the relevant queries before deleting the lot. Everything is now fine.  When Workbench was restarted before I carried this out there were > 150 tabs - it appears once it has got past some critical point WB happily duplicates (and more) tabs. User has been warned to keep number of tabs in single figures and document as appropriate.